# Solve for r. Logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$ 36000 = 3450 * \frac{1-[1/(1+r)^{12}]}{r} $$

The next step is divide both sides by 3450. Now I'm stuck. Help solve for r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by $3450$ and multiply by $r$.  This gives $$\frac{240}{23}r=1-(1+r)^{-12}$$$$(1+r)^{-12}=1-\frac{240}{23}r$$$$1=(1+r)^{12}[1+\frac{240}{23}-\frac{240}{23}(r+1)]$$So that$$\frac{263}{23}(1+r)^{12}-\frac{240}{23}(r+1)^{13}-1=0$$This represents a $13^{th}$ ordered polynomial equation for $r+1$, which has generally 13 roots.